# When the free loop space fibration splits?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

Let $X$ be a (nice) connected topological space. Let $LX=Map(S^1,X)$ be the free loop space and $\Omega X = Map_*(S^1,X)$ the subspace of based loops (with some choice of base point for X). Now, there is a fiber sequence
$$
\Omega X \to LX\to X
$$

where the map $LX\to X$ is evaluation at the base point. I am interested in the following question:

> Under what general conditions this sequence splits and we have a (weak) homotopy equivalence $LX \simeq X\times \Omega X$ ?

This is of course not true in general. In the case of a classifying space $BG$ of a discrete group $G$, we have $LBG$ equivalent to a disjoint union of $BC(x)$ where $x$ runs over conjugacy classes of $G$ and $C(x)$ is its centralizer subgroup (as explained nicely in the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88090/the-connected-components-of-the-free-loop-space) MO question). Hence, the splitting holds if and only if $G$ is abelian.

#### Partial Results

I have managed to prove this in the case where $X$ itself is of the homotopy type of a based loop space. i.e. $X\simeq \Omega Y$ for some $Y$ and a little bit more generally, when $X\simeq Map_*(W,Y)$ for some (nice) connected pointed space $W$ and some pointed space $Y$. There are several ways to see this, but the slickest proof I got is just a sequence of standard adjunctions. Denote by $X_+$ the based space obtained from $X$ by adding a disjoint base point. On the one hand,

$$
LX = Map(S^1,Map_*(W,Y))=Map_*(S^1_+,Map_*(W,Y))=Map_*(S^1_+\wedge W,Y)
$$
and on the other,
$$
\Omega X\times X=Map_*(S^1 \vee S^0,Map_*(W,Y))=Map_*((S^1 \vee S^0)\wedge W,Y)
$$

The only difference between $S^1_+$ and $S^1\vee S^0$ is in the selection of the base point, but since $W$ is *connected*, after smashing with it we get a connected space so the choice of the base point does not matter.

Generalizing the loop space case, it is natural (I think) to ask whether this is true for a general H-space. I also have a feeling that this has something to do with vanishing of whitehead products, but this is just a guess.

Comment: The result you cite about $BG$ doesn't require the hypothesis that $G$ is finite.

Comment: Right. I will edit it. Thanks.

Comment: This question was reposted and [answered](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207844/when-does-the-free-loop-space-fibration-split) in MathOverflow.